# How can I repair this rotten entry threshold?

Tags: doors, sill, threshold

My entry door threshold is sunk into the concrete from the driveway and leaking.

How can I repair this sunken threshold?

OR, what kind of contractor should I get to repair it for me?

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen!  Make sure to show what is wrong with the threshold as well as any problems with the concrete or otherwise that contributed.

Comment: You can add photos by editing your post and use the button that looks like Mountains to upload a photo. Alternatively, upload them to a photo-sharing site like Imgur and edit your post to include the link, our helpful mods will embed the photo in the post for easier access.

Comment: Not sure why this got three upvotes, but it should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to confirm without pictures, but you might have a void below the wood where water gets in and is causing the wood to rot.

Remove the rubber gasket, then remove the metal threshold (if you have one). Next remove the rotted wood. You may have to cut away since the wood will run under the jamb.  Fill the void (if there is one) with quick setting concrete. Then just replace the wood. Use pressure treated wood to prevent rotting.

OR, just hire a repair/handyman.